# javascript style.display not working with buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see, I try to make two input buttons (one is shown, the other is hidden) that when clicked, displays the other and hides itself.  `btn` displays a canvas as well as `btn2` when clicked but `btn2`'s `onclick` method doesn't run.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
btn2.style.display = "none";

btn.onclick = function () {
    btn.style.display = "none";
    btn2.style.display = "block";
    document.body.innerHTML += '<canvas id="someId"></canvas>';

};

btn2.onclick = function() {
    btn2.style.display = "none";
  btn1.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("someId").remove();
};
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<input id='btn' type="submit" value='REMOVE THAT!!!'></input>
<input id="btn2" type="submit" value="return to menu" display="none"></input>
```

Comment: why do you have display here: <input id="btn2" type="submit" value="return to menu" display="none"></input>

Comment: one more thing: "btn1" dont exist, use "btn" instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<canvas id="someId"></canvas>';
```

You're appending to the HTML of the body, which is bad practice because it has to re-render all elements and as such, you've lost the click handler for btn2.

The solution is to append the canvas as an element like so:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.id = 'someId';
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

Now, the browser will append the canvas without destroying and recreating any other elements.

Also, you used `btn1` which does not exist, change to `btn`.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
btn2.style.display = "none";

btn.onclick = function () {
    btn.style.display = "none";
 btn2.style.display = "block";
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.id = 'someId';
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

};

btn2.onclick = function() {
 btn2.style.display = "none";
  btn.style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("someId").remove();
};
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<input id='btn' type="submit" value='REMOVE THAT!!!'></input>
<input id="btn2" type="submit" value="return to menu" display="none"></input>
```